# Start Docker Containers In Specific Order After Reboot

Tags: docker

### Context

Almost all of my docker containers are web applications that run on port 80. To allow them to all run on a single host, I allow docker to assign a random unused port, and use the `jwilder/nginx-proxy` ([reference](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/)) as a reverse proxy. **This requires the jwilder/nginx-proxy to be running before the container has started,** which is easy enough in the bash script I run to start the container after it has been built:

```
...
#######################
# ensure that we are running the frontend proxy 
# which allows us to run multiple web containers
RESULT=`docker ps | grep jwilder | wc -l`

if [ $RESULT -gt 0 ];then
    echo "found frontend proxy."
else
    echo "Deploying frontend proxy"
    docker run -d \
    -p 80:80 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -t jwilder/nginx-proxy
fi
#######################


# Now start the container.
docker run -d \
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=$VIRTUAL_HOST \
-p 80 \
-p 443 \
--name="$PROJECT_NAME" \
$CONTAINER_IMAGE
```

### The Problem

Often I need to reboot my servers and I need a solution that will start all my containers automatically and in the right order.

I can use the docker run paramater `--restart=always` to have all of my running containers start up automatically after a reboot, however, how can I ensure that my reverse proxy container starts first before anything else, and there is a short delay before any of the other containers are started (in any order).

Ideally, I would like a solution that would *not* be distro specific, such as using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) rather than writing an upstart or systemd startup script, but I need a way to hook into triggering after the docker daemon has finished starting successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) port 80 on all your containers with webapplications you could [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) to them to your Nginx container.

Here is a small sample `docker-compose.yml`:

```
app:
    build: app/
    expose:
        - "80"

api:
    build: api/
    expose:
        - "80"

webserver:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
        - app
        - api
```

And here the configuration for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}

upstream app {
    server app:80;
}

upstream api {
    server api:80;
}
```

When you link a container to another container (in this case to Nginx) Docker changes the `/etc/hosts` file and add lines like this:

> 172.17.0.7    api 165637cfd4ab yourproject_api_1
>
> 172.17.0.5    app dedf870dec53 yourproject_app_1

So Nginx knows about the api and app containers.

When a request comes in at 'localhost:80' Nginx will proxy it to `http://app:80`. The `hosts` resolves a request to `htt://app` to `172.17.0.7` and so this request is forwarded to the app container.

Start all containers with `$ docker-compose up` and you're done.

Comment: I *believe* this won't work for me because I need to be able to dynamically deploy *any number* of web applications, all that require this *single* shared reverse proxy, rather than each application spinning up its own reverse proxy. I don't know how many web apps I will have on each server, and my move them around. Also, would docker compose automatically ensure that the reverse proxy being linked to would startup before the web app on reboot? Perhaps you are relying on another script figuring out if docker is already running and calling `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Programster:  Docker will bring up a container before any of the containers that link to it, so this approach would seem to make sense. You just have to specify --link proxy:proxy when starting your containers.

Comment: @AdrianMouat can each of my web applications have essentially the same compose file, and after the first one was started, subsequent calls to the other compose files would realise the reverse proxy was up and use that? My webapps are deployed independently/randomly across multiple hosts but need to share the reverse proxy if it is already running on the host and only deploy it if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: I guess I'm suggesting don't use compose but still use the --link trick to ensure ordering when containers come back up.

Comment: There are more solutions such as systemd and ansible. If you use systemd you can't use --restart though. See http://container-solutions.com/2015/04/running-docker-containers-with-systemd/ if you want to go that route.

Comment: It turned out that my assumptions were wrong. The reverse proxy does NOT need to be running before the web apps, so you can just add `restart=always` to the bash script when starting the reverse proxy and the container itself. For some reason some of my containers were failing to start apache on boot, so I will look into using supervisord inside the container to ensure apache is running.